# how to recover camera rotation from kinect depth video?

Tags: kinect, openni

I use Kinect and openNI to record an sequence depth video with fixed angle.

What I want to do is to recover virtual camera rotation from the video, so that I can simulate  the video is taking from the top view.

I know I can physically to do that. Even so, I still need to do some calibration and recover camera rotation a little bit.

Where should I start from?

Answer (score 1):

The problem itself is known as "Camera Pose Estimation". You may want to look at the available literature about this topic, there should be also an implementation of it inside ROS operating system. Among the technique used to accomplish this task, there are also Structure From Motion and VSLAM algorithms borrowed from the robotics field :-)

Comment: Thanks Dexter!! Really appreciated! But I found another way to do this! I just used openni's projecttorealworld! And it's really helpful!

Comment: @HuanWu I have googled for 'openni' and 'projecttorealworld' and found nothing. Can you post a link to this part of the API / code / program for others? Thank you.

Comment: I think Huan Wu is talking about the utility function to convert projective coordinates to real world coordinates in OpenNI. Check the _ConvertProjectiveToRealWorld_ method of the _xn::DepthGenerator_ object!